# why is JmsTemplate.receive method returning a null object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I'm using **Mockito** to create a mock message object(inorder to test a `ibmMqService`) but `jmsTemplate` is returning a `null`

```
public class ImqMqServerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    IbmMqService ibmMqService;

    @Mock
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${ibm.mq.queue.response}")
    String responseMq;

    void receiveOrderResponseTest() throws JMSException {
        jmsTemplate.send(responseMq, new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                BytesMessage bytesMessage = session.createBytesMessage();
                String msg = "Test";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                bytesMessage.writeBytes(msg.getBytes());
                return bytesMessage;
            }
        });

        Message message = jmsTemplate.receive(responseMq);
        System.out.println(message.getJMSMessageID()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean `jmsTemplate` is `null` or `jmsTemplate.receive(responseMq)` returns `null`?

Comment: That is the default behavior of mocks - you have to tell Mockito what to do when each method is called (it's called stubbing).

Comment: Why shouldn't it return `null`? You are using a mock `JmsTemplate`. The default behavior of a mock is to return `null` when nothing is registered for that method. Your `send` method, doesn't do anything either (as that is called on the same mock as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Gary said, we need to stub the `session` `createBytesMessage()` method.

You can use an anonymous class to initialize the `BytesMessage` interface.

That initialization of `ByteMessage` interface can be given when the `session` mock `createBytesMessage()` method is called as below.

```
@ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Test {
    @Mock
    JmsSession session
   
    @Test
    void test() {
        BytesMessage message  = new BytesMessage() {
            // implementation 
        };
        doReturn(message).when(session).createBytesMessage();
        
        // Your Test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File does not seem to be declared as a Spring bean anywhere. Add the `@Service` annotation on it.
and

`@Autowired JmsTemplate jmsTemplate`